# Django Signals and celery , is Sync

Tags: django, celery, django-signals

I am using celery to scrap some URLs , and pushing the scrap data to an API
but because of  quick calls on this API 
i need to use Django Signals if it Sync

Answer (score 0):

you can use periodic tasks in celery can you give more specific details what you want to exactly do

Comment: I am scrap URLs ok i am running 40 Concurrency for one worker 
each scrap details once it scrapped it moved to Shopify API , so this make load and exceed 2 call per second for Shopify API , so i thinking if  i make scrapper just scrap and store into database and once record created in database Django signal call the API , if the Django Signal is Snyc i think it will be go smooth

Comment: I am scrap URLs ok i am running 40 Concurrency for one worker 
each scrap details once it scrapped it moved to Shopify API , so this make load and exceed 2 call per second for Shopify API , so i thinking if  i make scrapper just scrap and store into database and once record created in database Django signal call the API , if the Django Signal is Snyc i think it will be go smooth